# Why can a but sentence be a complete sentence?

Tags: grammar

Even today, Google has no problem making plenty of money. **But** **the fact that it is getting a little harder is still painful.**

I learn that "but" is a conjunction word. It is also used for joining two different ideas. Why is the sentence above in bold a complete one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *but* at the beginning of a sentence is a very common stylistic choice in **more informal writing**. Native speakers regularly begin sentences with *but* in both casual and formal speech, so this aims to make the text **feel more natural**. In a strictly grammatical sense, the bolded sentence is not "complete" because it isn't independent. But think about where the word *but* is normally used: to connect two ideas where the second contradicts or nuances the first. In the excerpt you've provided, *but* is clearly linking two ideas in this way--the ideas just happen to be expressed in separate sentences instead of separate clauses. I've even done it myself above in this paragraph :)

If I were an editor reading over the passage you provide, I would only change the use of *but* if the context was very formal. As a general rule, if you aren't using contractions, don't start a sentence with *but*.

(You can find many examples of people starting sentences with *But* in articles, books, magazines, etc. Google ""But that was just the tip of the iceberg." for a pretty common example)

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd just add that this applies to any conjunction. In informal speech or writing we often begin a sentence with "And", but the same considerations apply.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the bolded sentence ... isn't independent*"? That sentence is an *independent clause*, despite having a conjunction in front of it. If you mean something else, please be clear because "independent" is a technical term that contrasts with "dependent/subordinate".

Comment: @gotube I mean to suggest that ordinarily the series of words "but the fact that it is getting a little harder is still painful" appears as a dependent clause, linked to a preceding independent clause by a comma and the word "but." Therefore I wouldn't be surprised to hear a strict editor say "this is a dependent clause; remove the 'but'." Now as you say this isn't true in modern (descriptivist) grammar, but (I feel) it reflects a folk analysis pedantic readers are likely to make.